# Java numeric sequence

Tags: java, sequence

I want to make a numeric sequence from 1 to 30 but showing only even numbers.

```
public class pruebita {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 0;
        while (x >= 30) {
            x++;
            if (x % 2 == 0) System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `while(x>=30)`  - x will never be greater than 30.

Comment: You need to loop while x is **less** than or equals to 30, not **greater** than.  Alternatively, since you have a specific number of times you want to go through the loop, use a for-loop instead.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: And if you use a `for` loop you can also avoid the `if` test.

Answer (score 1):

In you code `x=0` so the code  `while(x>=30){}`(while condition is false) will not execute because `x` is less than 30. You can change the code to  `while(x<=30){}` so the while condition is true.

In **java 8** you can do

```
java.util.stream.IntStream.range(x, 31)
                          .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
                          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the sign so that the `while` loop is entered

```
while (x <= 30) {
```